# Searching for strings in sdtout queue using Python

Tags: python, queue

I am trying to get my head around Queues.  I am in the process of piping stdout to a queue, I then want to end the pipe and search through the queue for two strings.  I have tried the method below, but I think my grasp on queues may be incorrect.

here's my attempt:

```
alldone = 0
string1found = 0
string2found = 0

MYprocess = subprocess.Popen('adb logact', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print "\t\tADB logging on!"

stdout_queue = Queue.Queue()
stdout_reader = AsynchronousFileReader(MYprocess.stdout, stdout_queue)
stdout_reader.start()

MYtimeout = time.time() + duration


while not stdout_reader.eof():
    while not stdout_queue.empty():

        if (time.time() > MYtimeout) and not alldone:
            alldone = 1

if alldone:
    print "Checking log"
    fulllist = stdout_queue.get()
    MYSTRING1 = re.search(r'first string', fulllist)
    MYSTRING2 = re.search(r'second string', fulllist)

    if MYSTRING1:
        string1found = 1
        print 'String 1 found'

    if MYSTRING2:
        string2found = 1
        print 'String 2 found'
```

I tried the get() command on the queue, but I think it's only reading the last line of the queue, so the strings are never found.

Comment: [`Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) returns one item from the queue.

Comment: .get() returns one item, the first item in the queue. Im not sure there's a good way to read the queue like you are trying. Any reason you're not using a list instead ?

Comment: Your regex is excessive. You can just say `if 'first string' in fulllist:`

Comment: I think you're over-complicating this. You probably don't need AsynchronousFileReader or a Queue. What exactly do you want to do? Is it to print `String 1 found` and `String 2 found` at most once if they're found anywhere in the output, or to print them out for each line they're found on?

Comment: @MikG, did one of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, I decided to go for the while get() option as it was easiest to implement for now, but as you mention I can now see that I am over complicating things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) removes and returns one item from the queue.

You probably want to loop until it is empty:

```
while stdout_queue:
    line = stdout_queue.get()
    # etc
```

Answer (score 0):

.get() will only return one item, the first one (first in, first out!)

You could do something like this to read the queue to a list, but why not just use a list to begin with instead?

```
def string_in_queue(q):
    while q:
        item = q.get()
        if item == string1:
            return item
    print "String not found"
```

Note that this will destroy your queue, as .get() will *remove* the items from the queue entirely.

Use a list instead!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating this. You don't need AsynchronousFileReader or a Queue. This will read the process output line-by-line, printing out 'found' messages as it finds the strings:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # For Python 2/3 support

import subprocess

demo_search_strings = (
    (u'String 1', u'Hello'),
    (u'String 2', u'World'),
    )


def main(search_strings):
    # DO NOT use shell=True! I'm ONLY using it here for a quick,
    # undistracting example of a process with delays in output.
    cmd = u'echo Hello World;' + u'sleep 3; echo Hello; sleep 2; echo World;'
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd * 4, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

    for line in iter(lambda: process.stdout.readline().decode(), ''):
        for ss_name, search_string in search_strings:
            if search_string in line:
                print(u"{ss_name} found".format(ss_name=ss_name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(demo_search_strings)
```